# Ensure that only one instance of a class gets run

Tags: python, singleton

I have an underlying class which I want to place in some code.  I only want it to be instantiated or started once for a given app although it might be called many times..  The problem with the code below is that LowClass is started over and over again.  I only want it to start once per test..

```
import logging

class LowClass:

    active = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger()
        self.log.debug("Init %s" % self.__class__.__name__)
        if self.active:
            return
        else:
            self.active = True
        self.log.debug("Now active!")

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger()
        self.log.debug("Init %s" % self.__class__.__name__)
        self.lowclass = LowClass()

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger()
        self.log.debug("Init %s" % self.__class__.__name__)
        self.lowclass = LowClass()

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger()
        self.log.debug("Init %s" % self.__class__.__name__)
        self.a = A()
        self.b = B()


class ATests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def testOne(self):
        a = A()
        b = B()

    def testTwo(self):
        c = C()
```

Thanks for pointing out my problem!!

Comment: With the proper name in hand -- "singleton" -- there's now a number of questions discussing this topic on SO (like Alex Martelli's Borg pattern, et alii). Vote for close now that asker has appropriate term for the design pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [singleton in python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52558/).

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to implement the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) Design pattern in python

I've found this [implementation](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52558/) I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Look up "singleton pattern".  It looks like Python you are dealing with, so you might have to search a bit harder.  I now there are plenty of examples in C++.

Answer (score 2):

When you import a module in python, it is natural singleton.
For example,
in util.py, you have:

```
   class MyClass(object):
        ......

    g_my_obj = MyClass()
```

in a.py, you import g_my_obj:

```
from util import g_my_obj
```

in b.py, you import g_my_obj again:

```
from util import g_my_obj
```

Safely, there is only one g_my_obj created no matter how many times you import it.

Comment: Much clearer and easier than other answer and doesn't need a custom class to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem with the code shown is that you set `self.active=True`. This will create an attribute for the instance and set that to `True`, whereas I believe that you want to set the active of the class itself to `True`. So, instead of `self.active=True`, try `self.__class__.active=True`.