# Python code: to initialise only one instance of a class

Tags: python, singleton, single-instance

Sorry novice beginner programmers question about having only one instance of a class run at one time; and now struggling to find right way to structure the code.

I've researched but struggling to find the right approach, but lots of argument as to the right pythonic approach be that modules or Singltons e.g. [Ensure that only one instance of a class gets run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575680/ensure-that-only-one-instance-of-a-class-gets-run)

I have some code (python 2.7.2) that continually logs 3 variables (2 temperatures and a pressure sensor) and then based on some logic looking at trends in the variables, moves a valve (if statements that if true, call defs in the module with lots of globals scattered around as I actually want all my defs to look at the same datasets and move the same valve). At the minute this all works fine in a module file.

However, so others in the lab can run my code, it needs to be launched from a general GUI and therefore my code needs to be threaded so that the process doesn’t tie up the GUI and command line.

I'd started to re-write the code into a Class (with threading superclass), and wanted to add some logic to that only one instance of the Class was called, so that >1 thread isn’t trying to control the same valve.

Now, I've discovered that this isn’t so easy in python and read that the notion of 'Singletons' are bad, and am struggling to find a solution on how to structure my code.

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction, as I guess this must have been answered.

Comment: I think threading each controller may be overkill for you.  Sounds like what you need is some sort of deamon or other manager thread that loops over a set of valve controller objects, then an interface that lets you tell the manager to add or remove controllers and a way to query the manager for the state of all currently running controllers.  Does that sound about right?

Comment: Singleton pattern has its place, like everything else. It's become a naughty word because it's often abused. If I understand right, this project (multiple UIs, one controller) seems like a good time to use the model-view-controller pattern. [Here's the Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) Alternatively, maybe a single web interface for everyone would be a good fix?

Answer (score 1):

you should initalize one instance and access only your initialized constant
and for safety, raise exception in case someone tries to create another instance

```
class Singletone(object):
    __initialized = False
    def __init__(self):
        if Singletone.__initialized:
            raise Exception("You can't create more than 1 instance of Singletone")
        Singletone.__initialized = True

MY_SINGLETONE_INSTANCE = Singletone()
```

Answer (score -1):

From http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html:

```
def singleton(object, instantiated=[]):
    "Raise an exception if an object of this class has been instantiated before."
    assert object.__class__ not in instantiated, \
        "%s is a Singleton class but is already instantiated" % object.__class__
    instantiated.append(object.__class__)

class YourClass:
    "A singleton class to do something ..."
    def __init__(self, args):
        singleton(self)
        ...
```

Not sure how you'd have to adapt that for multithreaded applications, though.

Comment: Apart from the horribleness of singletons (and it's not written in stone a singleton has to be used here), this is a pretty questionable implementation of singletons.

Comment: A singleton pattern will return the same instance of an object every time it is instantiated. This code will just raise an assertion if ever a second instance is requested. I guess in the end you still get only one instance, but...

Comment: That's what I like about it. It's a different approach. Instead of being able to indiscriminately access the Singleton, which is essentially just another name for global state, it forces the user to think through which object is responsible for managing the lifetime of and access to whatever object you want to be a Singleton.